# Can I target css selectors in specific order?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two div tags:

1. `div class="one two three"`
2. `div class="three two one"`

Could I construct a `css` rule that targets only `".one.two.three"` but not `".three.two.one"` ?

Comment: out of curiosity, may I ask why you want this behavior ?

Comment: I want to know because (1) I need to target some badly designated css and (2) I am a soul in search for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
div[class="one two three"] {}
```

But you should pay attention to whitespace as they count and can make your selector invalid

Comment: Why is this marked as a "Community Wiki"...that seems unnecessary?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Probably because this is a frequently asked question and Temani doesn't want the easy rep, and as usual the canonical eludes us so we have to settle for providing an answer to a strictly-speaking-duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

**selector: [attr=value]**

Example:

```css
[class="one two three"] {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p class="one two three">123</p>
<p class="three two one">321</p>

</body>
</html>
```